# how do i access the class list value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

[image]

I have a class which populates without a problem from a rest server and it binds

the class is

```
namespace SavRMobile.AccessToken
{

    public class AccessTokenModel
    {
        public User user { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public Accesstoken[] accessTokens { get; set;}
    }

    public class Accesstoken
    {
        public string appId { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }


}
```

there will only ever be 1 token that i need to retrieve. I dont know why the developers made it into a list? anyways i want to access the accesstoken.value property.. it get returned as an array..  I cant seem to get the value even in a foreach it will not let me. or should i just grad the index of [0] but not sure what the approach is?

Comment: how you doing that foreach ? there shoudldn't be any issue in accessing that property

Comment: recievedAccessToken.User.Accesstoken[0].value ?

Comment: `ReceivedAccessToken.User.accessTokens[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
AccessTokenModel receivedAccessTokens = new AccessTokenModel();
if (receivedAccessTokens.user.accessTokens.Length > 0)
{
   string appID = receivedAccessTokens.user.accessTokens[0].appId;
   string value = receivedAccessTokens.user.accessTokens[0].value;
}
```

In the definition of the class `accessTokens` is defined as an array of `Accesstoken` so you have to access their values based on the index. It is always better to check for the Array Length/items count before accessing a value based on the index. so above code will do that checking as well as retrieving the values for appId and value.

Comment: thank you your solution worked for me. add the extra data of appid, value to the end of the formula was all that was missing and to also check the length before doing so.. thanks for all responses

Answer (score 1):

You can call it like this:

```
 if(RecievedAccessToken.User.accessTokens.Length > 0)
 {
   ReceivedAccessToken.User.accessTokens[0].value;
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: you should be check ReceivedAccessTokens.User.accessTakens length

Comment: ReceivedAccessTokens does not exist in the current context? is my error from this solution

Answer (score 0):

**Get spesific Index value**

```
 if(recievedAccessToken.User.Accesstoken.Length > 0)
  {
     recievedAccessToken.User.Accesstoken[0].value
  }
```

or

```
  //Check `length`
  AccessTokenModel tokens = recievedAccessToken.User.Accesstoken[0];
```

**Return result List**

```
AccessTokenModel receivedAccessTokens = new AccessTokenModel();

foreach (AccessTokenModel act in recievedAccessToken)
{
  receivedAccessTokens.Add(act);
}
```